# Can't find Spotify on APP Store (In a permitted country)

Tags: iphone, applications, ios-appstore, spotify

I tried to download Spotify on my iPhone but unfortunately, I can't find the on the App Store, So, I did some search on Google and I found that I have to make sure that my country is allowed

I searched for my country on the official website  https://support.spotify.com/us/article/where-spotify-is-available/ and fortunately, my country "Morocco" exists on the list, but no result on the App Store, any solution?

Comment: What country is your Apple ID registered in?

Comment: @fsb is registered in France